# python strptime vs dateutil - recommended use

Tags: python, python-dateutil

I need to convert between strings and datetime objects quite often - up until now i have always used strptime and strftime. 
I started working with the google calendar API where i recieve strings like this: '2018-03-17T09:00:00+01:00

It seems like i need to convert the +01:00 into 0100 for strptime which is a little annoying.
While i dont have this issue with dateutil there are a few other inconveniences.Also i saw that the last update of dateutil was in 2016 which seems odd.

So my question is which one would you recommend for adding and substracting dates and datetimes and switching between string and datetime obj?
Also is dateutil still maintained or is it outdated?

Thanks a lot!
- Sally

Comment: dateutil has no updates because it already works fine - it has no outstanding bugs and lots of tests, you should use it regardless of age

Comment: Who told you that the last update of dateutil was 2016? The last [release to PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/#history) was 2.7.3 on 10 May 2018. The [last commit to GitHub](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/) was 11 August 2018.

Comment: If you're using Python 2.6 or 3.2 or something, it may be that the last version of `dateutil` that works with your Python was 2 years ago, but that's just because you're using a Python that's way past end-of-life, not because `dateutil` is.

Answer (score 6):

> It seems like i need to convert the +01:00 into 0100 for strptime

No you don't.

For one thing, the standard format is `+0100`, not `0100`.

For another, `strptime` handles `+01:00` just fine:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-08-13T11:18:24+00:00', 
...                            '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 13, 11, 18, 24, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-08-13T11:18:24+01:00', 
...                            '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 13, 11, 18, 24, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=3600)))
```

So, the problem you're trying to solve doesn't exist in the first place.

---

> While i dont have this issue with dateutil there are a few other inconveniences.Also i saw that the last update of dateutil was in 2016 which seems odd.

As of 13 Aug 2018, [the last update to `dateutil`](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/) was 2 days ago. And the last [official release to PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/#history), version 2.7.3, was 3 months ago.

So, your secondary problem doesn't exist either.

---

> So my question is which one would you recommend for adding and substracting dates and datetimes and switching between string and datetime obj?

Since `dateutil` just gives you the same `datetime` objects that `datetime` gives you, neither one is better for adding and subtracting dates and datetimes.

For converting to and from string format, sometimes `dateutil` is more convenient, and it also supports a wider range of formats that you don't care about—but for what you're doing, they both work fine, so there's no difference. If you expect to need other formats in the future, it might be worth bringing in `dateutil`, but if not, you might as well stick with the standard library.

Comment: It's also worth noting that a [parser for ISO-8601](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/blob/master/dateutil/parser/isoparser.py) strings was added in 2.7 which is as fast as strptime in most tests.

Comment: @BradSolomon Yeah, I didn’t mention “`dateutil` is slow” as a reason not to use it, because it’s often not true anymore (and often isn’t relevant anyway). The main reason to choose is: Does it make your code (or likely future extensions to your code) simpler? If not, don’t use it. If so, use it unless specific perf tests show you can’t.

Comment: Well this is weird... because i receive this error: time data '2018-08-09T08:00:00+02:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'
It works fine without the time zone so i´m a bit confused.

It seems i was redirected to a outdated version of the documentary so your right, i should have noticed that.

Comment: @SallyZeitler What version of Python are you using? If it’s 2.7 or 3.3 or something equally old, `datetime` isn’t nearly as good as recent versions; there are backports available,  but once you need that, the decision process changes. A `datetime` backport might be better if you’re planning to migrate to Python 3.6 soon; `dateutil` might be better if you have a pile of old 2.6-era code that you can barely afford to do the basics to get it working with 2.7.

Comment: @SallyZeitler In particular, IIRC, before around 3.4, `dateutil` delegated a lot of work to the platform’s date parser, which is of course different on Linux vs. macOS/*BSD vs. Windows, so how they handle some fields is not documented or portable.

Comment: @abarnert I´m using python 3.6.6 so that not the problem. It might be because i´m working with django but it seems highly unlikely. I´ll dig around for a solution tonight since this behaviour has something to do with my environment but if i dont get anything until tomorrow i´ll probably switch to dateutil.
Thanks for your answer, it really cleared things up!

PS: I´m working on manjaro - the django project is in a venv

Answer (score 2):

`dateutil` last version (2.7.3) is in may 2018. It just says "copyright 2016" somewhere in the credits. Moreover, the documentation talks about policy for future versions, so it seems to be quite active. I would suggest to prefer it over `strptime`. However, *be sure to get the latest version*. Previous versions had a bug with converting ISO dates, with which you are working.

Comment: Oh I must´ve missed something because i read the docs and it said "Last released: Nov 8, 2016" 
Thanks a lot, i´ll upgrade asap!